# tinycap always captured 0 frames?

Tags: android, audio-recording, microphone, soundcard, tinyalsa

I’m using an OPPO FindX5 pro (with 3 MICs) to record system-audio, and I refer to `tinycap`. However, I cannot record via it.

Step1: I checked the sound card

```
OP5209L1:/proc/asound # cat cards
 0 [waipiomtpsndcar]: waipio-mtp-snd- - waipio-mtp-snd-card
                      waipio-mtp-snd-card
```

Step2: I check which devices can be used to record, where we observe "6-11 / 14 16 18 20 21 22 24 26 28" are with capture capbility.

```
OP5209L1:/proc/asound # cat devices
  2: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
  3: [ 0- 1]: digital audio playback
  4: [ 0- 2]: digital audio playback
  5: [ 0- 3]: digital audio playback
  6: [ 0- 4]: digital audio playback
  7: [ 0- 5]: digital audio playback
  8: [ 0- 6]: digital audio capture
  9: [ 0- 7]: digital audio capture
 10: [ 0- 8]: digital audio capture
 11: [ 0- 9]: digital audio capture
 12: [ 0-10]: digital audio capture
 13: [ 0-11]: digital audio capture
 14: [ 0-12]: digital audio playback
 15: [ 0-13]: digital audio playback
 16: [ 0-14]: digital audio capture
 17: [ 0-15]: digital audio playback
 18: [ 0-16]: digital audio capture
 19: [ 0-17]: digital audio playback
 20: [ 0-18]: digital audio capture
 21: [ 0-19]: digital audio playback
 22: [ 0-20]: digital audio capture
 23: [ 0-21]: digital audio playback
 24: [ 0-22]: digital audio capture
 25: [ 0-23]: digital audio playback
 26: [ 0-24]: digital audio capture
 27: [ 0-25]: digital audio playback
 28: [ 0-26]: digital audio capture
 29: [ 0-27]: digital audio playback
 30: [ 0-28]: digital audio playback
 31: [ 0-29]: digital audio capture
 33:        : timer
 34: [ 0]   : control
```

Step3: I try to record sound, but it just warns "Captured 0 frames". Maybe I missed config the `tinymix`?

```
OP5209L1:/proc/asound # tinycap /sdcard/file.wav -D 0 -d 16 -c 2
Capturing sample: 2 ch, 44100 hz, 16 bit
Captured 0 frames
```

But How can I config the tinymix, with lots of options?

```
OP5209L1:/proc/asound # tinymix
Mixer name: 'waipio-mtp-snd-card'
Number of controls: 310
ctl     type    num     name                                     value

0       BOOL    1       TX_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC0                   Off
1       BOOL    1       TX_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC1                   Off
2       BOOL    1       TX_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC2                   Off
3       BOOL    1       TX_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC3                   Off
4       BOOL    1       TX_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC4                   Off
5       BOOL    1       TX_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC5                   Off
6       BOOL    1       TX_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC6                   Off
7       BOOL    1       TX_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC7                   Off
8       BOOL    1       TX_AIF2_CAP Mixer DEC0                   Off
9       BOOL    1       TX_AIF2_CAP Mixer DEC1                   Off
10      BOOL    1       TX_AIF2_CAP Mixer DEC2                   Off
11      BOOL    1       TX_AIF2_CAP Mixer DEC3                   Off
12      BOOL    1       TX_AIF2_CAP Mixer DEC4                   Off
13      BOOL    1       TX_AIF2_CAP Mixer DEC5                   Off
14      BOOL    1       TX_AIF2_CAP Mixer DEC6                   Off
15      BOOL    1       TX_AIF2_CAP Mixer DEC7                   Off
16      BOOL    1       TX_AIF3_CAP Mixer DEC0                   Off
17      BOOL    1       TX_AIF3_CAP Mixer DEC1                   Off
18      BOOL    1       TX_AIF3_CAP Mixer DEC2                   Off
19      BOOL    1       TX_AIF3_CAP Mixer DEC3                   Off
20      BOOL    1       TX_AIF3_CAP Mixer DEC4                   Off
21      BOOL    1       TX_AIF3_CAP Mixer DEC5                   Off
22      BOOL    1       TX_AIF3_CAP Mixer DEC6                   Off
23      BOOL    1       TX_AIF3_CAP Mixer DEC7                   Off
24      ENUM    1       TX DMIC MUX0                             ZERO
25      ENUM    1       TX DMIC MUX1                             ZERO
26      ENUM    1       TX DMIC MUX2                             ZERO
27      ENUM    1       TX DMIC MUX3                             ZERO
28      ENUM    1       TX DMIC MUX4                             ZERO
29      ENUM    1       TX DMIC MUX5                             ZERO
30      ENUM    1       TX DMIC MUX6                             ZERO
31      ENUM    1       TX DMIC MUX7                             ZERO
32      ENUM    1       TX SMIC MUX0                             ZERO
33      ENUM    1       TX SMIC MUX1                             ZERO
34      ENUM    1       TX SMIC MUX2                             ZERO
35      ENUM    1       TX SMIC MUX3                             ZERO
36      ENUM    1       TX SMIC MUX4                             ZERO
37      ENUM    1       TX SMIC MUX5                             ZERO
38      ENUM    1       TX SMIC MUX6                             ZERO
39      ENUM    1       TX SMIC MUX7                             ZERO
40      ENUM    1       TX DEC0 MUX                              MSM_DMIC
41      ENUM    1       TX DEC1 MUX                              MSM_DMIC
42      ENUM    1       TX DEC2 MUX                              MSM_DMIC
43      ENUM    1       TX DEC3 MUX                              MSM_DMIC
44      ENUM    1       TX DEC4 MUX                              MSM_DMIC
45      ENUM    1       TX DEC5 MUX                              MSM_DMIC
46      ENUM    1       TX DEC6 MUX                              MSM_DMIC
47      ENUM    1       TX DEC7 MUX                              MSM_DMIC
48      INT     1       TX_DEC0 Volume                           84
49      INT     1       TX_DEC1 Volume                           84
50      INT     1       TX_DEC2 Volume                           84
51      INT     1       TX_DEC3 Volume                           84
52      INT     1       TX_DEC4 Volume                           84
53      INT     1       TX_DEC5 Volume                           84
54      INT     1       TX_DEC6 Volume                           84
55      INT     1       TX_DEC7 Volume                           84
56      ENUM    1       DEC0 MODE                                ADC_DEFAULT
57      ENUM    1       DEC1 MODE                                ADC_DEFAULT
58      ENUM    1       DEC2 MODE                                ADC_DEFAULT
59      ENUM    1       DEC3 MODE                                ADC_DEFAULT
60      ENUM    1       DEC4 MODE                                ADC_DEFAULT
61      ENUM    1       DEC5 MODE                                ADC_DEFAULT
62      ENUM    1       DEC6 MODE                                ADC_DEFAULT
63      ENUM    1       DEC7 MODE                                ADC_DEFAULT
64      ENUM    1       TX0 HPF cut off                          CF_NEG_3DB_4HZ
65      ENUM    1       TX1 HPF cut off                          CF_NEG_3DB_4HZ
66      ENUM    1       TX2 HPF cut off                          CF_NEG_3DB_4HZ
67      ENUM    1       TX3 HPF cut off                          CF_NEG_3DB_4HZ
68      ENUM    1       TX4 HPF cut off                          CF_NEG_3DB_4HZ
69      ENUM    1       TX5 HPF cut off                          CF_NEG_3DB_4HZ
70      ENUM    1       TX6 HPF cut off                          CF_NEG_3DB_4HZ
71      ENUM    1       TX7 HPF cut off                          CF_NEG_3DB_4HZ
72      BOOL    1       DEC0_BCS Switch                          Off
73      BOOL    1       TX_SWR_DMIC Enable                       Off
74      ENUM    1       BCS Channel                              CH0
75      ENUM    1       BCS CH_SEL                               SWR_MIC6
76      ENUM    1       RX_MACRO RX0 MUX                         ZERO
77      ENUM    1       RX_MACRO RX1 MUX                         ZERO
78      ENUM    1       RX_MACRO RX2 MUX                         ZERO
79      ENUM    1       RX_MACRO RX3 MUX                         ZERO
80      ENUM    1       RX_MACRO RX4 MUX                         ZERO
81      ENUM    1       RX_MACRO RX5 MUX                         ZERO
82      ENUM    1       IIR0 INP0 MUX                            ZERO
83      ENUM    1       IIR0 INP1 MUX                            ZERO
84      ENUM    1       IIR0 INP2 MUX                            ZERO
85      ENUM    1       IIR0 INP3 MUX                            ZERO
86      ENUM    1       IIR1 INP0 MUX                            ZERO
87      ENUM    1       IIR1 INP1 MUX                            ZERO
88      ENUM    1       IIR1 INP2 MUX                            ZERO
89      ENUM    1       IIR1 INP3 MUX                            ZERO
90      ENUM    1       RX MIX TX0 MUX                           ZERO
91      ENUM    1       RX MIX TX1 MUX                           ZERO
92      ENUM    1       RX MIX TX2 MUX                           ZERO
93      ENUM    1       RX INT0 DEM MUX                          NORMAL_DSM_OUT
94      ENUM    1       RX INT1 DEM MUX                          NORMAL_DSM_OUT
95      ENUM    1       RX INT0_2 MUX                            ZERO
96      ENUM    1       RX INT1_2 MUX                            ZERO
97      ENUM    1       RX INT2_2 MUX                            ZERO
98      ENUM    1       RX INT0_1 MIX1 INP0                      ZERO
99      ENUM    1       RX INT0_1 MIX1 INP1                      ZERO
100     ENUM    1       RX INT0_1 MIX1 INP2                      ZERO
101     ENUM    1       RX INT1_1 MIX1 INP0                      ZERO
102     ENUM    1       RX INT1_1 MIX1 INP1                      ZERO
103     ENUM    1       RX INT1_1 MIX1 INP2                      ZERO
104     ENUM    1       RX INT2_1 MIX1 INP0                      ZERO
105     ENUM    1       RX INT2_1 MIX1 INP1                      ZERO
106     ENUM    1       RX INT2_1 MIX1 INP2                      ZERO
107     ENUM    1       RX INT0_1 INTERP                         ZERO
108     ENUM    1       RX INT1_1 INTERP                         ZERO
109     ENUM    1       RX INT2_1 INTERP                         ZERO
110     ENUM    1       RX INT0_2 INTERP                         ZERO
111     ENUM    1       RX INT1_2 INTERP                         ZERO
112     ENUM    1       RX INT2_2 INTERP                         ZERO
113     ENUM    1       RX INT0 MIX2 INP                         ZERO
114     ENUM    1       RX INT1 MIX2 INP                         ZERO
115     ENUM    1       RX INT2 MIX2 INP                         ZERO
116     BOOL    1       RX INT2_1 VBAT RX AUX VBAT Enable        Off
117     INT     1       RX_RX0 Digital Volume                    81
118     INT     1       RX_RX1 Digital Volume                    81
119     INT     1       RX_RX2 Digital Volume                    82
120     INT     1       RX_RX0 Mix Digital Volume                84
121     INT     1       RX_RX1 Mix Digital Volume                84
122     INT     1       RX_RX2 Mix Digital Volume                84
123     BOOL    1       RX_COMP1 Switch                          Off
124     BOOL    1       RX_COMP2 Switch                          Off
125     INT     1       RX0 FIR Coeff Num                        0
126     INT     1       RX1 FIR Coeff Num                        0
127     ENUM    1       HPH Idle Detect                          OFF
128     ENUM    1       RX_EAR Mode                              OFF
129     ENUM    1       RX_FIR Filter                            OFF
130     ENUM    1       RX_HPH HD2 Mode                          OFF
131     ENUM    1       RX_HPH_PWR_MODE                          ULP
132     ENUM    1       RX_GSM mode Enable                       OFF
133     BOOL    1       RX_Softclip Enable                       Off
134     BOOL    1       AUX_HPF Enable                           On
135     INT     1       IIR0 INP0 Volume                         54
136     INT     1       IIR0 INP1 Volume                         84
137     INT     1       IIR0 INP2 Volume                         84
138     INT     1       IIR0 INP3 Volume                         84
139     INT     1       IIR1 INP0 Volume                         84
140     INT     1       IIR1 INP1 Volume                         84
141     INT     1       IIR1 INP2 Volume                         84
142     INT     1       IIR1 INP3 Volume                         84
143     BOOL    1       IIR0 Enable Band1                        Off
144     BOOL    1       IIR0 Enable Band2                        Off
145     BOOL    1       IIR0 Enable Band3                        Off
146     BOOL    1       IIR0 Enable Band4                        Off
147     BOOL    1       IIR0 Enable Band5                        Off
148     BOOL    1       IIR1 Enable Band1                        Off
149     BOOL    1       IIR1 Enable Band2                        Off
150     BOOL    1       IIR1 Enable Band3                        Off
151     BOOL    1       IIR1 Enable Band4                        Off
152     BOOL    1       IIR1 Enable Band5                        Off
153     BYTE    20      IIR0 Band1                                00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
154     BYTE    20      IIR0 Band2                                00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
155     BYTE    20      IIR0 Band3                                00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
156     BYTE    20      IIR0 Band4                                00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
157     BYTE    20      IIR0 Band5                                00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
158     BYTE    20      IIR1 Band1                                00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
159     BYTE    20      IIR1 Band2                                00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
160     BYTE    20      IIR1 Band3                                00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
161     BYTE    20      IIR1 Band4                                00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
162     BYTE    20      IIR1 Band5                                00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
163     BYTE    404     RX0 FIR Coeff Group0                      
164     BYTE    404     RX0 FIR Coeff Group1                     
165     BYTE    404     RX1 FIR Coeff Group0                      
166     BYTE    404     RX1 FIR Coeff Group1                    
167     BOOL    1       VA_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC0                   Off
168     BOOL    1       VA_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC1                   Off
169     BOOL    1       VA_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC2                   Off
170     BOOL    1       VA_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC3                   Off
171     BOOL    1       VA_AIF2_CAP Mixer DEC0                   Off
172     BOOL    1       VA_AIF2_CAP Mixer DEC1                   Off
173     BOOL    1       VA_AIF2_CAP Mixer DEC2                   Off
174     BOOL    1       VA_AIF2_CAP Mixer DEC3                   Off
175     BOOL    1       VA_AIF3_CAP Mixer DEC0                   Off
176     BOOL    1       VA_AIF3_CAP Mixer DEC1                   Off
177     BOOL    1       VA_AIF3_CAP Mixer DEC2                   Off
178     BOOL    1       VA_AIF3_CAP Mixer DEC3                   Off
179     ENUM    1       VA DMIC MUX0                             ZERO
180     ENUM    1       VA DMIC MUX1                             ZERO
181     ENUM    1       VA DMIC MUX2                             ZERO
182     ENUM    1       VA DMIC MUX3                             ZERO
183     ENUM    1       VA SMIC MUX0                             ZERO
184     ENUM    1       VA SMIC MUX1                             ZERO
185     ENUM    1       VA SMIC MUX2                             ZERO
186     ENUM    1       VA SMIC MUX3                             ZERO
187     ENUM    1       VA DEC0 MUX                              MSM_DMIC
188     ENUM    1       VA DEC1 MUX                              MSM_DMIC
189     ENUM    1       VA DEC2 MUX                              MSM_DMIC
190     ENUM    1       VA DEC3 MUX                              MSM_DMIC
191     INT     1       VA_DEC0 Volume                           84
192     INT     1       VA_DEC1 Volume                           84
193     INT     1       VA_DEC2 Volume                           84
194     INT     1       VA_DEC3 Volume                           84
195     BOOL    1       LPI Enable                               Off
196     BOOL    1       VA_SWR_DMIC Enable                       Off
197     ENUM    1       VA_DEC0 MODE                             ADC_DEFAULT
198     ENUM    1       VA_DEC1 MODE                             ADC_DEFAULT
199     ENUM    1       VA_DEC2 MODE                             ADC_DEFAULT
200     ENUM    1       VA_DEC3 MODE                             ADC_DEFAULT
201     INT     1       HPHL Impedance                           0
202     INT     1       HPHR Impedance                           0
203     INT     1       HPH Type                                 0
204     ENUM    1       RX HPH Mode                              CLS_H_ULP
205     ENUM    1       TX0 MODE                                 ADC_NORMAL
206     ENUM    1       TX1 MODE                                 ADC_NORMAL
207     ENUM    1       TX2 MODE                                 ADC_NORMAL
208     ENUM    1       TX3 MODE                                 ADC_NORMAL
209     BOOL    1       HPHL_COMP Switch                         Off
210     BOOL    1       HPHR_COMP Switch                         Off
211     BOOL    1       LDOH Enable                              Off
212     BOOL    1       ADC2_BCS Disable                         Off
213     INT     1       HPHL Volume                              20
214     INT     1       HPHR Volume                              20
215     INT     1       ADC1 Volume                              12
216     INT     1       ADC2 Volume                              12
217     INT     1       ADC3 Volume                              12
218     INT     1       ADC4 Volume                              12
219     ENUM    1       ADC1 ChMap                               ZERO
220     ENUM    1       ADC2 ChMap                               ZERO
221     ENUM    1       ADC3 ChMap                               ZERO
222     ENUM    1       ADC4 ChMap                               ZERO
223     ENUM    1       DMIC0 ChMap                              ZERO
224     ENUM    1       DMIC1 ChMap                              ZERO
225     ENUM    1       MBHC ChMap                               ZERO
226     ENUM    1       DMIC2 ChMap                              ZERO
227     ENUM    1       DMIC3 ChMap                              ZERO
228     ENUM    1       DMIC4 ChMap                              ZERO
229     ENUM    1       DMIC5 ChMap                              ZERO
230     ENUM    1       DMIC6 ChMap                              ZERO
231     ENUM    1       DMIC7 ChMap                              ZERO
232     INT     1       Haptics Amplitude Step                   178
233     INT     1       TFA98XX Volume                           0
234     INT     1       TFA98XX ANA Volume                       7
235     ENUM    1       SPK_Pa Revision                          OK
236     ENUM    1       Speaker_Mute_Switch                      Off
237     ENUM    1       TFA_CHECK_FEEDBACK                       Off
Failed to mixer_ctl_get_array
Failed to mixer_ctl_get_array
Failed to mixer_ctl_get_array
Failed to mixer_ctl_get_array
238     BYTE    0       HDMI EDID                                239    BYTE    0       HDMI MS EDID                             240       BYTE    0       Display Port EDID                        241    BYTE    0 Display Port1 EDID                       242     ENUM    1       External Display Type                    (null)
243     ENUM    1       External Display1 Type                   (null)
244     ENUM    1       External HDMI Type                       (null)
245     ENUM    1       External Display Audio Ack               (null)
246     ENUM    1       External Display1 Audio Ack              (null)
247     ENUM    1       External HDMI Audio Ack                  (null)
248     INT     2       External Display Audio Device            0 0
249     INT     2       External Display1 Audio Device           0 0
250     INT     2       External HDMI Device                     -1 -1
251     BOOL    1       BT SOC status                            Off
252     BOOL    1       BT set feedback channel                  Off
253     INT     1       SP PCMID                                 65653
254     INT     1       SP MIID                                  16987
255     BYTE    80      CODEC_DMA-LPAIF_RXTX-RX-0 Channel Map
256     BYTE    80      CODEC_DMA-LPAIF_RXTX-RX-1 Channel Map
257     BYTE    80      CODEC_DMA-LPAIF_RXTX-RX-2 Channel Map
258     BYTE    80      CODEC_DMA-LPAIF_RXTX-RX-3 Channel Map
259     BYTE    80      CODEC_DMA-LPAIF_RXTX-RX-5 Channel Map 
260     BYTE    80      CODEC_DMA-LPAIF_RXTX-RX-6 Channel Map 
261     BYTE    80      CODEC_DMA-LPAIF_RXTX-TX-3 Channel Map  
262     BYTE    80      CODEC_DMA-LPAIF_RXTX-TX-4 Channel Map  
263     BYTE    80      CODEC_DMA-LPAIF_VA-TX-0 Channel Map  
264     ENUM    1       PM_QOS Vote                              Disable
265     BYTE    80      CODEC_DMA-LPAIF_VA-TX-1 Channel Map  
266     BYTE    80      CODEC_DMA-LPAIF_VA-TX-2 Channel Map  
267     BYTE    80      SLIM-DEV1-RX-7 Channel Map  .....
268     BYTE    80      SLIM-DEV1-TX-7 Channel Map  .....
269     BOOL    1       AMIC1_MIXER Switch                       Off
270     BOOL    1       AMIC2_MIXER Switch                       Off
271     BOOL    1       AMIC3_MIXER Switch                       Off
272     BOOL    1       AMIC4_MIXER Switch                       Off
273     BOOL    1       AMIC5_MIXER Switch                       Off
274     BOOL    1       AMIC6_MIXER Switch                       Off
275     BOOL    1       AMIC7_MIXER Switch                       Off
276     BOOL    1       VA_AMIC1_MIXER Switch                    Off
277     BOOL    1       VA_AMIC2_MIXER Switch                    Off
278     BOOL    1       VA_AMIC3_MIXER Switch                    Off
279     BOOL    1       VA_AMIC4_MIXER Switch                    Off
280     BOOL    1       VA_AMIC5_MIXER Switch                    Off
281     BOOL    1       VA_AMIC6_MIXER Switch                    Off
282     BOOL    1       VA_AMIC7_MIXER Switch                    Off
283     ENUM    1       ADC2 MUX                                 INP2
284     ENUM    1       ADC3 MUX                                 INP4
285     ENUM    1       ADC4 MUX                                 INP5
286     ENUM    1       HDR12 MUX                                NO_HDR12
287     ENUM    1       HDR34 MUX                                NO_HDR34
288     BOOL    1       ADC1_MIXER Switch                        Off
289     BOOL    1       ADC2_MIXER Switch                        Off
290     BOOL    1       ADC3_MIXER Switch                        Off
291     BOOL    1       ADC4_MIXER Switch                        Off
292     BOOL    1       DMIC1_MIXER Switch                       Off
293     BOOL    1       DMIC2_MIXER Switch                       Off
294     BOOL    1       DMIC3_MIXER Switch                       Off
295     BOOL    1       DMIC4_MIXER Switch                       Off
296     BOOL    1       DMIC5_MIXER Switch                       Off
297     BOOL    1       DMIC6_MIXER Switch                       Off
298     BOOL    1       DMIC7_MIXER Switch                       Off
299     BOOL    1       DMIC8_MIXER Switch                       Off
300     ENUM    1       RDAC3_MUX                                RX1
301     BOOL    1       EAR_RDAC Switch                          Off
302     BOOL    1       AUX_RDAC Switch                          Off
303     BOOL    1       HPHL_RDAC Switch                         Off
304     BOOL    1       HPHR_RDAC Switch                         Off
305     BOOL    1       SWR DAC_Port Switch                      Off
306     ENUM    1       TFA Profile                              speaker
307     BOOL    2       TFA Stop                                 Off Off
308     INT     2       TFA Calibration                          6623 6643
309     INT     1       TFA_CHIP_SELECTOR                        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$ tinymix` while recording by recorder APP to get the tinymix config.Or find it in `./vendor/qcom/opensource/audio-hal/primary-hal/configs/taro/diting/mixer_paths_overlay_static.xml`,and qcom use agmcap instead of tinycap.
In my case:

```
tinymix "TX DEC1 MUX" "SWR_MIC"
tinymix "TX SMIC MUX1" "SWR_MIC4"
tinymix "TX_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC1" "1"
tinymix "ADC1 ChMap" "SWRM_TX2_CH1"
tinymix "TX0 MODE" "ADC_LP"
tinymix "ADC1_MIXER Switch" "1"
tinymix "AMIC1_MIXER Switch" "1"
tinymix "TX DEC3 MUX" "SWR_MIC"
tinymix "TX SMIC MUX3" "SWR_MIC9"
tinymix "TX_AIF1_CAP Mixer DEC3" "1"
tinymix "ADC4 MUX" "INP5"
tinymix "ADC4 ChMap" "SWRM_TX3_CH2"
tinymix "TX3 MODE" "ADC_LP"
tinymix "ADC4_MIXER Switch" "1"
tinymix "AMIC5_MIXER Switch" "1"
tinymix "ADC1 Volume" "8"
tinymix "ADC4 Volume" "8"


agmcap /data/test.wav -D 100 -d 115 -c 2 -r 48000 -b 16 -i CODEC_DMA-LPAIF_RXTX-TX-3
```